# Delete all my NSUserDefaults that start with a certain word

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults

Is there a way for me to "walk" through a list of all the `NSUserDefault`s in my iPhone app, and only delete certain ones?

For example, I'd like to get all the key names that start with a certain word.

Something like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"Dog*"];
```

Answer (score 19):

You can look through the [`dictionaryRepresentation`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHBAJHA).

Here's an implementation which uses [`NSPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) as a generic matcher for greater flexibility.

```
@interface NSUserDefaults (JRAdditions)
- (void)removeObjectsWithKeysMatchingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate;
@end

@implementation NSUserDefaults (JRAdditions)

- (void)removeObjectsWithKeysMatchingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate {
   NSArray *keys = [[self dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys];
   for(NSString *key in keys) {
      if([predicate evaluateWithObject:key]) {
         [self removeObjectForKey:key];
      }
   }
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH %@", @"something"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectsWithKeysMatchingPredicate:pred];
```

Answer (score 0):

i Got solution for this just use it where you want to remove all sessions

```
 NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

it will work