# Delete all keys from a NSUserDefaults dictionary iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I use the NSUserDefaults dictionary to store basic information such as high scores etc so that when the user closes the app data is not lost. Anyways I use:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

to store data. If I wish to store a new high score for example then I would do:

```
[prefs setInteger:1023 forKey:@"highScore"];
[prefs synchronize];  //this is needed in case the app is closed.
```

and later if I wish to retrieve the high score I would do:

```
[prefs integerForKey:@"highScore"];
```

anyways the point is that I store a lot of other things because the `NSUserDefaults enable` you to store `booleans`, `integers`, `objects` etc.   what method would I have to execute to delete all keys so that NSUserDefaults becomes like the fist time I launch the app?

I am looking for something like:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs deleteAllKeysAndObjectsInTheDictionary];
```

or maybe there is a way of getting all keys and I have to loop through each object but I don't know how to remove them.

EDIT:

I have tried :

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
[prefs synchronize];
```

and I still am able to retrieve a high score....

Comment: See this related Question, [Delete all my NSUserDefaults that start with a certain word](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3436792/642706), with a [good answer about using a NSPredicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3436840/642706) to find certain entries in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

If you have a look at the [NSUserDefaults documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you will see a method `- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryRepresentation`.  Using this method on the standard user defaults, you can get a list of all keys in the user defaults.  You can then use this to clear the user defaults:

```
- (void)resetDefaults {
    NSUserDefaults * defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary * dict = [defs dictionaryRepresentation];
    for (id key in dict) {
        [defs removeObjectForKey:key];
    }
    [defs synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Shortest way to do this with the same results:`______________________________________________`    
`NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];` `__________________`
`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];  `

Comment: This is not the best way of doing it since it will iterate and attempt to remove *all* user defaults keys including the system ones instead of just the app ones. Using -removePersistentDomainForName: as suggested in the other answer is much better.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use [dict removeAllObjects] instead of looping over the whole dictionary?

Comment: @FitterMan no, that only removes objects from the dictionary, not from `NSUserDefaults`…

Answer (score 75):

**Shortest way to do this with the same results** like in Alex Nichol's top answer:

```
NSString *appDomain = NSBundle.mainBundle.bundleIdentifier;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: How to clear NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName.

Comment: Don't forget to `synchronize` your NSUserDefaults right after if you are using defaults in a way that will require that.

Comment: Note that KVO observers won't be notified when removing a complete domain (though a notification is posted). For KVO compatibility it's probably better to iterate through each key returned from `persistentDomainForName` and remove it with `removeObjectForKey`.

Answer (score 45):

One-liner:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:NSBundle.mainBundle.bundleIdentifier];
```

Comment: Don't forget to `synchronize` your NSUserDefaults right after if you are using defaults in a way that will require that.

Comment: As of iOS 11, synchronize is deprecated.

Answer (score 34):

**Simple Solution**

***Objective C:***

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

**Swift 3.0 to Swift 5.0 :**

```
if let appDomain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
    UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: appDomain)
}
```

Answer (score 16):

`+ (void) resetStandardUserDefaults` doesn't persist the changes, it simply resets the in-memory user defaults object so that the next `synchronize` call will read from the on-disk copy, instead of overwriting existing in-memory values with the on-disk versions.

Iterating over the keys is better, but there's actually a function that does this for you: [`removePersistentDomainForName:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHCDBFJ).

```
// you can usually get the domain via [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
 removePersistentDomainForName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
// or use a string for any other settings domains you use
//[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
// removePersistentDomainForName:@"com.mycompany.myappname"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

At the end of the `synchronize` operation, both the disk and memory copies of user defaults will contain none of the values set by your application.

Answer (score 16):

Swift version:

```
if let bid = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(bid)
}
```

Comment: optional not unwrapped, does not adhere to Swift best practices

Comment: Yes, although bundle identifier is not likely to be nil if you're using main bundle, it's recommended to use Juan's code.

Answer (score 11):

Oneliner in Swift:

**Swift 3**

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(
NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!)
```

**Swift 4**

```
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
```

Comment: Swift 4.0   -----  UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

Comment: @GerardGrundy You don't need `.synchronize()`. You never do in such normal situations. Contents are automatically saved.

Comment: @Moritz Though if the app shut down before it had time to automatically save then you would need to force save.

Comment: Also, `synchronize` is not just "save". `synchronize` saves *and* loads the whole defaults object (which can be bigger than expected). It is never necessary to call `synchronize` in order to "save" defaults. If you call it, you must have a good reason, and those are rare. ;)

Answer (score 10):

For those of you that want to do this in the test target, use this (as the `removePersistentDomain` does not work for that case)

**Swift 3:**

```
for key in Array(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys) {
     UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
}
```

Comment: Best solution when you do not want to depend on main bundle. In my case I was loading an specific bundle, and I was not sure if keys were really removed.

Answer (score 5):

***For Swift 3:***

```
let appDomain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: appDomain)
```

Answer (score 5):

For Swift 3:

```
if let bundle = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
    UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: bundle)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift

```
func resetUserDefaults(){
  let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  let dict = userDefaults.dictionaryRepresentation() as NSDictionary
        
  for key in dict.allKeys {
    userDefaults.removeObjectForKey(key as! String)
  }
        
  userDefaults.synchronize()      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift**
*place in your logic*

```
if let appDomain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
  UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: appDomain)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it the most handy to place the code in an extension on `UserDefaults`.

**Swift 5**

```
extension UserDefaults {
    static func clear() {
        guard let domain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier else { return }
        UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: domain)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
UserDefaults.clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this method not do that:

```
+ (void)resetStandardUserDefaults
```

From the documentation for `NSUserDefaults`:

> **resetStandardUserDefaults**
>
> Synchronizes any changes made to the shared user defaults object and
>   releases it from memory.
>
> `+ (void)resetStandardUserDefaults`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> A subsequent invocation of standardUserDefaults creates a new shared
>   user defaults object with the standard search list.

Based on this, you can do:

```
[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

and now the defaults should be reset.

Comment: when I call [NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults]; it does not delete anything.

Comment: It is my understanding that this relates to the standardUserDefaults shared object rather than the information stored on disk, meaning that this would have no noticeable effect on the saved user defaults.

Comment: @Tono: when you call `[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];` and *then* do `NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`, my understanding (which may be incorrect) is that `prefs` will be a blank slate once again.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, it's the same idea. I hadn't read your answer yet since I was engaged in discussion on mine. I'll remove the edit and defer to you for that approach.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 or 4** 
We can even simplify described snippet into this modern expression:

```
func clearAll() {
    let settingsDictionary = userDefaults.dictionaryRepresentation()
    settingsDictionary.forEach { key, _ in userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: key) }
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5.0 below single line of code is enough.

```
UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys.forEach(defaults.removeObject(forKey:))
```

Answer (score 0):

**To remove all UserDefault value in swift (Latest syntax)**

```
//remove UserDefaults
if let identifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
  UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: identifier)
  UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeAll()
```