# Check if NSDictionary is empty

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I want to check if an `NSDictionary` is empty. I am doing it like this.

```
  mutDictValues = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dicValues"]mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"dictValues are %@",mutDictValues);
    if(mutDictValues == NULL){
        arrCities = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSLog(@"no cities seleceted");
    }else{
          arrCities = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
          arrCities = [mutDictValues objectForKey:@"cities"];
          [self placeCities];
    }
```

But it alwasy crashes on this line `arrCities = [mutDictValues objectForKey:@"cities"];` with the following error:

```
-[__NSCFConstantString objectForKey:]:
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: if (![dictTemp isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        // do something
        DisplayAlert(@"No data found")
    }

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> While retrieving the dictionary values from NSUserDefaults that
>   dictionary automatically converted into string that is the reason for
>   getting crashed and for checking dictionary use
>
> ```
> [dictionary count];
> ```

EDIT:-
  use [dictionaryForKey:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  method

```
NSDictionary *dict =[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"hi",@"one",nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:@"dic"];
NSDictionary *dictn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"dic"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dictn objectForKey:@"one"]);
```

Comment: Is it possible to get this back as NSDictionary ?

Comment: once check this one,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797096/delete-all-keys-from-a-nsuserdefaults-dictionary-iphone

Comment: if (![dictTemp isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        // do something
        DisplayAlert(@"No data found")
    }

Answer (score 8):

```
if ( [mutDictValues count] == 0 ) {
    //code here
}
else {
    //code here
}
```

After having your dic retrieved this should do

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
if([myDict count] > 0)
    NSLog(@"Dictionary is not empty");
else
    NSLog(@"Dictionary is empty");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL containsKeyABC = [myDict: valueForKey:@"ABC"];

int items = dict.count;

if (items > 0) {
     //not empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere you treat a nsstring (a concrete subclass) as NSdictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I had a bit different issue but it is related so i would like to share it here.

I was fetching the webservices & storing data in NSDictionary & again Fetching objectForKey which was Null. So the solution i found is as under

```
NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];

    // NSLog(@"%@" , result);

    NSMutableDictionary *sup = [result objectForKey:@"keysupplied"];
    NSNull *n=[NSNull null];
    if ( sup ! = n ){
      //Your code if its not null
    }
```

The reason behind using NSNull was it was returning (NSNull *) when i debugged the application So i finally figured out this way.

Answer (score 0):

As most of the answers have correctly pointed out that you are passing un-recognized selector `objectForKey:` to a `NSString` instance instead of `NSDictionary`, hence observing exception

```
-[__NSCFConstantString objectForKey:]:
```

Check `NSUserDefaults` to see whether `cities` returns a dictionary or something else. You can do this by two ways

I. `NSLog` all data in `NSUserDefaults`

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

II. Check the plist file which store the `NSUserDefaults` from the Application folder. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1677104/1407017) for more details.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = ...

BOOL isEmpty = ([dict count] == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (myDict.count)
    NSLog(@"Dictionary is not empty");
else
    NSLog(@"Dictionary is empty");
```

Every number that is `0` equals to `@NO`.

Every number that is not `0` equals to `@YES`.

Therefore you can just pass the count into the `if`.