# What is the best way to keep the state of a modal UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a hard time to sum up my problem in one title so I'll try to be clear here.

I have a `UIViewController` (vc1) that links me to another `UIViewController` (vc2) through a segue.

In vc2 I can select a segment of a `UISegmentedControl`.

To go back to vc1, I simply press a return `UIButton` I made where the `@IBAction` is:

```
@IBAction func returnToMainView(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I would like that when I go back again to vc2, the segment I selected the first time is again selected.

What are my solutions?

Should I keep using the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` method and use a delegate method to save which index segment is selected. Then when I go back to vc2, pass the selected index segment in the segue calling for vc2?

Or is there a better way to keep the state of my vc2 than the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` ?

Hope I've been clear enough.

**UPDATE**:

Here is some more information on my case.

In vc1, I have a UITableView. On every row I can call my vc2 which will display information according to the row of course.

And actually, I want to save the state of this controller just for the current execution of the app. No need to persist the state

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `NSUserDefaults` for that. So If I open another ViewController, I save all important settings of my UIViews where needed.

In your example, before you dismiss your ModalViewController, you can save for example the state of your `UISegmentedControl`:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex, forKey: "yourSwitch")
```

Then, in the `viewWillApear` method of your ModalViewController, you call the `NSUserDefaults` and load all settings:

```
var selectedIndex = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("yourSwitch")
```

After that in the `viewDidAppear` method, you call the values:

```
segmendedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = selectedIndex
```

Comment: It still applies. Because you can remove the NSUserDefaults in your AppDelegate methods. For example if you restart the app, you can call it in the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method and remove all keys from the userdefaults. Check this question how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797096/delete-all-keys-from-a-nsuserdefaults-dictionary-iphone

Answer (score 0):

IMO if it is really just one segmented_control index you want to retain, save its index in your previous viewController and pass it anytime you present it via the `prepareForSegue:` method. Any other thing would be an overkill.

Comment: If I understand what you're proposing, this tightly couples VC2 to VC1 correct?

Comment: Yes it does, since the vc1 stores the vc2's state of the segmentedControl.

Comment: So we probably wouldn't want to do that. Writing tests would be pretty challenging.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this:

1. Delegate pattern. You can have VC1 implement `VC2Delegate` protocol which essentially acts as a callback
2. You can set a block property on VC2 from VC1 to perform some action to change the state of VC1 when the segmentedControl is augmented.
3. As some of the other answers mentioned, you could set some data model like Core Data or `NSUserDefaults`.
4. You could use NSNotifications. In my experience this can be tough for other engineers to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there are several ways to do this. Another way is to keep VC2 alive, rather than having it be deallocated when you dismiss it. You can do this by creating a property for it in VC1, and  only instantiating VC2 the first time you present it; you will have to present it in code, rather than using a segue, since segues always instantiate new controllers.

Comment: Thanks that might actually what I was looking for. In terms of performance, is it more or less the same? Any hint how to "present" a viewController?

Comment: @Nico, int terms of performance, since you're keeping a view controller alive, it will use more memory, but if it doesn't have a lot of images, then that memory penalty is pretty low. Also, if the user is going back and forth often, there's not much difference between keeping a controller alive versus creating new ones multiple times. To present a view controller you use presentViewController:animated:completion: which you should know from reading the "View Controller Guide for iOS". If you haven't read that, do so.