# In swift how do I remove all Defaults/NSUserDefaults values for a suite?

Tags: ios, swift3, nsuserdefaults

I'm using NSUserDefaults or Defaults with suite names.

For example:
`UserDefaults(suiteName: "AccountOne")?.set("Active", forKey: "AKey")`

I'd like to delete all keys and values for the given suite name: `AccountOne`

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797096/delete-all-keys-from-a-nsuserdefaults-dictionary-ios

Answer (score 6):

`UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: "AccountOne")`

Comment: Confusingly, (since we are referencing `standard`) this is the way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the `forName:` in removePersistentDomain has to be the same as `suiteName:` when creating the UserDefaults instance. The API naming is a bit misleading :(