# Remove NSUserDefaults for keys starting with

Tags: ios, swift, save, nsuserdefaults

I want to remove strings that are stored in the `NSUserDefaults` for the keys beginning with `"NavView"`.
I thought about using the `hasPrefix()` method, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I know that other programming languages have features like taking every string with a certain beginning by passing the prefix they want it to have like: find all strings with `"NavView*"` or something. (using signs like the star to indicate that)

Any ideas how I could do that except storing all the objects in an array and saving that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`UserDefaults` is one kind of key value pair persistent store. To solve your problem you have to follow the steps:

- Iterate over the all keys of UserDefaults Dictionary.
- Check each key has prefix "NavView".
- If key has the prefix then remove the object for the key.

Swift 4:

```
for key in UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys {
    if key.hasPrefix("NavView"){
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Objective C :

```
NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

for (NSString *key in [userDef dictionaryRepresentation].allKeys) {
    if ([key hasPrefix:@"start"]) {
        [userDef removeObjectForKey:key];
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. I didn't know about the `.keys`. I will try that, thanks already.

Comment: Thats my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 is the same as Swift 4

```
for key in UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys {
            if key.hasPrefix("NavView") {
                UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the keys and filter only the ones that start with the prefix.
See example - [Delete all my NSUserDefaults that start with a certain word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436792/delete-all-my-nsuserdefaults-that-start-with-a-certain-word)